# Unable to use ajax function to display tabs

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-ajax

How do I write and call a function to display/hide a div outside of the ajax  tag? Using the OnClick event handler (I displayed an alert message but the function is not working)

```
                        if ((data[i + 1].deviceName == data[i].deviceName) && (data[i + 1].protocol == data[i].protocol)) {
                            divbody += "<tr style=\"border-bottom:solid; border-width:thin\">";
                            divbody += "<th><input type=\"radio\" name=\"device\" onclick=\"alert('Hi_2')\" value=\"" + counter++ + "\"></th>";
                            divbody += picurl;
                            divbody += "<th style=\"padding:10px\">" + data[i].deviceName + "(" + data[i].protocol + ")" + "</th>";
                            divbody += "<th>" + data[i].display_Name + " : " + data[i].value + data[i].unit + " & " + data[i + 1].display_Name + " : " + data[i + 1].value + data[i + 1].unit + "</th > ";
                            divbody += "<th>" + data[i].timeStamp + "</th>";
                            divbody += "<th><img src=\"../wwwroot/images/Battery.png\" style=\"width:150px; height: 150px;\" /></th>";
                            divbody += "</tr>";
                            i++;
```

Radio button named 'device'

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[name$='device']").checked(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "#myTabs", success: function (result) {
                    $("#tbl-productos").html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Function attempt

Comment: Please don't share code via screenshots but via the code function

Comment: `$.ajax({url:"#myTabs"` ? Is that as ASP.net thing?

Comment: Please use the edit function to edit your post

Comment: @JohnTyner no I thought that was how to load divs

Comment: `url: "#myTabs"` - this should be an actual URL.

Comment: how do you load a div instead?

Comment: Hard to tell what you need. Maybe [this](https://api.jquery.com/load/)?